# As was he/As if he was

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> He's mingling around flirting with girls as was he James Bond.

> He's mingling around flirting with girls as if he was James Bond.

Which one is correct? (if any of them)

Comment: _As was he_ cannot be used in this context.

Comment: "as if he was/were James Bond" is the only correct option

Comment: @KateBunting - it sounds like something Chaucer might have written.

Comment: @KateBunting - I know it's wrong, but I like it.

Comment: [mingling and flirting with girls] not mingling around.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct. Ex.

> He talked as if he were my boss. But the truth is he isn't my boss.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct in the English that we use today, and this has been the case for many centuries I bet.

You might encounter the first one in some very archaic literature. But if you speak that way, it will be hard for people to understand it.

Comment: But if the text is that old, then it would have used the (now nearly obsolete) subjunctive: _as were he_. _As was he_ would have been ungrammatical then.